# Check for keyword in first and last line

Tags: php

i have the following string

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICtzCCAZ8CAQAwcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCQVUxETAPBgNVBAgMCFZpY3RvcmlhMRIw
EAYDVQQHDAlNZWxib3VybmUxDzANBgNVBAoMBk1LVEVTVDELMAkGA1UECwwCSVQx
HjAcBgNVBAMMFWRuc3Rlc3Q0LnNzbHRlY2hzLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBANRhwPJLWYTFS19kgWLs49wR1BR+qaeET26BHT4ZdmQi
iDKOFn1VzuBhv6bIWJpGrkBqM5oKkB6ckAjUlMKUNeCTiA0NAqvrAgM19GptzgIq
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I would like to be able to check the first and last line for the word "NEW" if its missing, then it should be added in.

The result should be like this:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICtzCCAZ8CAQAwcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCQVUxETAPBgNVBAgMCFZpY3RvcmlhMRIw
EAYDVQQHDAlNZWxib3VybmUxDzANBgNVBAoMBk1LVEVTVDELMAkGA1UECwwCSVQx
HjAcBgNVBAMMFWRuc3Rlc3Q0LnNzbHRlY2hzLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBANRhwPJLWYTFS19kgWLs49wR1BR+qaeET26BHT4ZdmQi
iDKOFn1VzuBhv6bIWJpGrkBqM5oKkB6ckAjUlMKUNeCTiA0NAqvrAgM19GptzgIq
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

i have this so far to retrieve the first line

```
$lines=explode("\n", $data);
echo $lines['0'];
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the checks you can just replace **BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST** with **BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST**.

Try this:

```
$string = str_replace(
  ['BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST', 'END CERTIFICATE REQUEST'],
  ['BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST', 'END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST'],
  $string
);
```

Comment: I like this solution best.. nice and elegant. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to check each line for something like this. Try the following:

```
preg_replace("/(begin|end) certificate/i", "$1 NEW CERTIFICATE", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (strpos($string,'NEW') == false) {
    str_replace('CERTIFICATE', "NEW  CERTIFICATE", $string);
}
```